# No result from DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I don't get any answer when I evaluate the following expression:

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == -0.5*y[t] + 1 + 3*(e^(-2*t)), 
        y'[t] == 2*x[t] - y[t] - 4 - 4* (e^(-t)), 
        y[0] == 0, x[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]} , t]
```

Did I go wrong somewhere?

I tried solving this equation set with `Laplace` as well, but I didn't get any answer from that either.

Comment: Is it `e`, or  `E` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing  the `.5`by `1/2` and the `e` by `E`. Also, the asterisks aren't needed in Mathematica.

```
s = DSolve[
 {x'[t] == -1/2 y[t] + 1 + 3 E^(-2 t),
  y'[t] == 2 x[t] - y[t] - 4 - 4 E^(-t),
  y[0]  == 0, 
  x[0]  == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]

ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. s, {t, 0, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: and `//FullSimplify` ;)

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Tried that, but the result isn't compact enough to look nice here. So I kept it like that.

Comment: That was more a tip for @DSaad than an edit suggestion :)

Answer (score 3):

Two problems here are `e` instead of `E` and `0.5` instead of `1/2`. For a larger system it would be more reasonable to use `Rationalize` instead of substituting all numbers by hand. To get a wider class of solutions we could define a function being a solution of the system of differential equations, where the initial values are parametrized by `x0`:

```
ds[x0_] = Simplify @ DSolve[ Rationalize @ {x'[t] == -0.5*y[t] + 1 + 3*(E^(-2*t)),
                                            y'[t] == 2*x[t] - y[t] - 4 - 4*(E^(-t)), 
                                            y[0] == 0, 
                                            x[0] == x0},     {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

[image]

originally `x0 == 0`, i.e.

```
ds[0]
```

[image]

To plot the wider class of solutions we could use `ParametricPlot` as in belisarius answer with `Show` emphasizing `ds[0]` solution as a red thick curve :

```
Show[
      ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. Table[ds[x0], {x0, -2, 4, 0.2}],
                                                   {t, -1, 10}, Evaluated -> True], 
      ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. ds[0], {t, -1, 10}, 
                                             PlotStyle -> {Darker@Red, Thickness[0.007]}],
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 6}, {-4, 5}}]
```

[image]