# DSolve to solve a system of differential equations

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I need to solve a system of differential equations as follows:

```
Clear[t]

system =
  { x'[t] ==  2.2758*y[t] - x[t]/200, 
    y'[t] == - 2*2.2758*E^(-(0.7071^2))*E^(-((1.77*t)^2/13.8^2))*Cos[-0.5*t]*z[t]
             + 2.2758*x[t]  - y[t]/200, 
    z'[t] == 2*2.2758*E^(-(0.7071^2))*E^(-((1.77*t)^2/13.8^2))*Cos[-0.5*t]*y[t]};
initialvalues = {x[0] ==  0, y[0] ==  0, z[0] ==  -1};

sol = DSolve[ Join[ system, initialvalues], {x, y, z}, t]
```

Unfortunately, *Mathematica* is not able to yield a result. Is there a way to do it?

Also I have another question. I want to make the values of  `x` , `y` and `z`   be numbers (numerical values) at `t == 0`. How I can do that ?

Comment: Working with `DSolve` you should replace machine precission numbers by exact ones. See a related problem here: [No result while try to DSolve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13210/no-result-while-try-to-dsolve).

Answer (score 3):

You can solve your problem numerically by switching to NDSolve and providing limits for t:

```
sol = NDSolve[Join[system, initialvalues], {u, v, w}, {t, -20, 0}]
Plot[{u[t], v[t], w[t]} /. sol, {t, -20, 0}]
```

[image]