# DSolve not outputting any result

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a system of differential equations using `DSolve`, but I am not getting any output beyond a repetition of my input:

```
DSolve[
 {p''[t] + 2 Cosh[c[t]] c'[t] p'[t]/Sinh[c[t]] == 0, 
  c''[t] - Sinh[c[t]] Cosh[c[t]] (p'[t])^2 == 0,
  c[0] == b, p[0] == 0,
  c'[0] == 0, p'[0] == 1},
 {c[t], p[t]}, t]
```

I saw [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13210/no-result-from-dsolve) question already, but I don't have any floating point numbers so that can't be the issue here. Why is `DSolve` not returning anything here?

Comment: Hi! and welcome to MSE! In general, nonlinear ODEs are difficult.  Do you know if this has a known symbolic solutIon? Otherwise, you might consider `ParametricNDSolve`, if a numerical approximation depending on the parameter `b` would be sufficient.

Comment: Hi! It should have a known solution, yes, I just don't know what it is. It's on a homework assignment so I assume it's doable, I just couldn't figure it out for the life of me so I turned to Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

This set of equations certainly is solvable analytically, although `DSolve` seems unable to do so without assistance.  Begin by solving the first equation only, applying the relevant boundary conditions, and solving algebraically for `p'[t]`.

```
Solve[Quiet@DSolve[{p''[t] + 2 Cosh[c[t]] c'[t] p'[t]/Sinh[c[t]] == 0, 
       c[0] == b}, c[t], t][[1, 1]] /. {p'[0] -> 1, Rule -> Equal}, p'[t]][[1, 1]]
(* Derivative[1][p][t] -> Csch[c[t]]^2 Sinh[b]^2 *)
```

This expression can be substituted into the second equation to yield a second order ODE for `c[t]` only, and this can be solved with `DSolve`, although applying the remaining boundary conditions is not straightforward.  So, consider multiplying the new ODE by `c'[t]` and integrating just once.

```
C[1] == Integrate[(c''[t] - Sinh[c[t]] Cosh[c[t]] (p'[t])^2 /. %) c'[t], t]
(* C[1] == 1/2 Coth[c[t]]^2 Sinh[b]^4 + 1/2 Derivative[1][c][t]^2 *)
```

The constant then can be evaluated to yield a first order ODE,

```
% /. t -> 0 /. {c[0] -> b, c'[0] -> 0}
%% /. (% /. Equal -> Rule)
(* 1/2 Cosh[b]^2 Sinh[b]^2 == 1/2 Coth[c[t]]^2 Sinh[b]^4 + 1/2 Derivative[1][c][t]^2 *)
```

which I must leave to the OP to solve, since I am out of time.