# Solve y'' -2y' - 3y = 6x + 5 and graph the family of Integral Curves and Highlights the curve that satisfies y(1) = 4, y'(1) = 2

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

```
DSolve[{y''[x] - 2 y'[x] - 3 y[x] == 6 x + 4 , y[1] == 4, y'[1] == 2},  y[x], x]
```

I don't know how to graph the family of Integral Curves and Highlights the curve that satisfies y(1) = 4, y'(1) = 2

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13210/no-result-from-dsolve/13212#13212) is related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use `ParametricNDSolve` to solve the parametric ODE `y[1] == a, y'[1] == b`. And then set `a=4, b=2` to draw the special case.

```
sols = ParametricNDSolve[{y''[x] - 2 y'[x] - 3 y[x] == 6 x + 4, 
    y[1] == a, y'[1] == b}, y, {x, -2, 2}, {a, b}];
curves = Plot[
   Table[y[a, b][x] /. sols, {a, 2, 5, .5}, {b, 1, 3, .5}], {x, -2, 
    2}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]];
curve = Plot[y[4, 2][x] /. sols, {x, -2, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[Large], Red}];
Show[curve, curves, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

We can also draw the curve individually.

```
sol = DSolve[{y''[x] - 2 y'[x] - 3 y[x] == 6 x + 4, y[1] == 4, 
    y'[1] == 2}, y[x], x];
f[x_] := y[x] /. First[sol];
p = {x, f[x]} /. x -> 1;
curve = Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 2}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[p], 
    Text[{y[1] == 4, y'[1] == 2}, p, Top]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1]
```